# Wildcards in delphi generics

Tags: delphi, generics

Знаю что в JAVA есть возможность объявления дженерика с маской `List<? extends Number>`. Существует ли возможность такой реализации на DELPHI?

Comment: Если я правильно понял `? extends Number` - позволит в результате создать только числовой список. В Delphi не встречал, но в целом можно создать свой класс вида: `TMyList<T: TBar> = class(TList<T>)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Подобный подход в Delphi называется [ограничениями](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Constraints_in_Generics).
В качестве ограничения вы можете указать, что тип `T` параметра:

- Поддерживает указанный интерфейс `TMyList<T: IMyInteface>`
- Является производным (унаследованным от) классом от указанного `TControlList<T:TWinControl>`
- Имеет конструктор по умолчанию (публичный, без параметров) `TTest<T:constructor>`
- Является классом `TMyObjectList<T:class>`
- является `value`-типом, т.е структурой, числом и т.п. `TValueList<T:record>`

Также вы можете указать несколько ограничений подряд, комбинируя некоторые из них (очевидно нельзя одновременно написать `class, record`). К примеру, `TTest<T: IMyInterface1, IMyInterface2>` (в данном случае должны выполняться оба условия).